# Adding multiple images to a PDF document with itext in android

Tags: java, android, itext

I am developing an android application in which i want to add multiple high resolution images to the pdf file with itext jar. I am getting an out of memory exception. When I set the smaller values for width and height it works fine. This is implemented inside a async background task class. The source code is as follows

```
fos = new FileOutputStream(pdfFilePath);
        //Rectangle pagesize = new Rectangle(595.44f, 841.68f);
        document = new Document(PageSize.A4, 0f, 0f, 0f, 0f);
        PdfWriter.getInstance(document,new FileOutputStream(pdfFilePath));

        fileArray  = imageDirectory.listFiles();
        Log.d("Files", "Size: "+ fileArray.length);
        for (i=0; i < fileArray.length; i++){
            document.open();
            bMap= BitmapFactory.decodeFile(fileArray[i].getPath(), null);
            bMap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bMap, 2339, 1654, false);
            matrix = new Matrix();
            matrix.postRotate(90);
            bMap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bMap, 0, 0, bMap.getWidth(), bMap.getHeight(), matrix, false);
            bMap = toGrayscale(bMap);
            stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            bMap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 25, stream);
            byteArray = stream.toByteArray();
            document.add(Image.getInstance(byteArray));
            Log.e("Files", "FileName:" + fileArray[i].getName());

            bMap = null;
            matrix = null;
            byteArray = null;
            stream = null;
            document.close();
        } 

        fos.close();
```

Comment: This isn't really an iText question. `Bitmap` isn't an iText object. Processing images takes CPU and memory. If you say that your code works when reducing the image size, you have proof that there's nothing wrong with the code. It's only normal that bigger size images require more resources. If those resources aren't available, exceptions get thrown.

Answer (score 0):

See: [Managing Bitmap Memory](https://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/manage-memory.html).

You probably want to call `bMap.recycle()` before setting it to `null`.